# Stop jQuery button animation on last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/z3q2wtLf/29/light/embedded/result/

In the attached jsfiddle link above .cd-hero has 3 slides that are activated by click. I'm trying to add a stop event to the jQuery only on the third slide ("thank you") so that the user stops on that slide (doesn't slide right or go back to the previous slides). I am new to jQuery any help on how to achieve this is much appreciated!

I have tried applying the below without success:

```js
$('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if($(this).hasClass('.thanks')){
       event.stopPropagation();
      } else {
        var activePosition = $('.cd-hero-slider .selected').index();
        var selectedPosition =  activePosition + 1;
        nextSlide($('.cd-hero-slider'), $(''), selectedPosition);

        updateNavigationMarker(selectedPosition + 1);
      }
  });
```

Comment: what wrap functions nextSlide and updateNavigationMarker into IF statement like a IF(position < 3) ...?

Comment: add an id or classs to button (a) that says 'Thank you' and then something like $('#ThankYou').click(function(e) {e.preventDefalut()})

Answer (score 1):

If you take the suggestion to add a class to the thank you button (e.g. `thanks`), you could start out the initial click event with an if statement that does something other than continue with the animation. Something like:

**CODE**:

```
$('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if($(this).hasClass('.thanks')){
       //do something other than animate the slides
      } else {
        var activePosition = $('.cd-hero-slider .selected').index();
        var selectedPosition =  activePosition + 1;
        nextSlide($('.cd-hero-slider'), $(''), selectedPosition);

        updateNavigationMarker(selectedPosition + 1);
      }
  });
```

Comment: I tried  $('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
   
   
    if($(this).hasClass('thanks')){
    event.stopPropagation();
     
    } else {
    
            var activePosition = $('.cd-hero-slider .selected').index();
            var selectedPosition =  activePosition + 1;
            nextSlide($('.cd-hero-slider'), $(''), selectedPosition);
    
          updateNavigationMarker(selectedPosition + 1);
           });   However, this doesn't work?